# Makefiles with C programming

Tags: c, macos, unix, text, makefile

I am very new to C and UNIX systems programming. I know what to put in a basic makefile (the  c files, the dependencies and the commands) but how do I actually create a makefile? Is it a text file? What kind of extension is a makefile? I am using Mac OSX, here is my current error

```
$ make -f Makefile.txt
lint pr2.2.c
make: lint: Command not found
make: *** [pr2-lint] Error 127
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's just a plain text file. The standard name is literally `makefile`.

Comment: Your makefile appears to be accepted just fine, so that doesn't seem to be the problem. However, `make` is trying to run the program `lint`, but can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

makefiles are text files.  They typically don't have an extension.  The most common name is Makefile with a capital M.  You can use any text editor to create one.

Comment: How do I make one then? What do I physically do on the computer to create a makefile? Do i open up text-edit in OSX and write my commands? (i tried that and I have been getting some errors

Comment: Open a text editor, create a text file, save it with the name Makefile. It's the text you put in it that matters. For that, I recommend a book.

Comment: in Mac OSX text-edit only saves between .rtf and a bunch of word documents, and html

Comment: @Code: No, TextEdit will save plain text files. Check the options in the main menu for one that allows you to convert a document to plain text. I know it's there, but I don't recall exactly where.

Answer (score 1):

A `Makefile` is a text file with no extension and it specify's the rules of **when** and **how** to compile and link a source file.

To create a makefile just open a text file and name it as `Makefile` after you modify it.

A simple tutorial like **[this](http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/TutMakefile.htm)** should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

It is a text file. It is usually named `Makefile` with no extension.

Comment: Oh also, don't forget to use actual tabs instead of spaces!

Comment: What do you mean by tabs instead of spaces?